# Broken Project Netbeans 8.2 for Linux

Tags: java, linux, netbeans

I'm having trouble with my Netbeans 8.2 in Elementary OS. I uploaded a project from another computer (with Windows) to Github. But then when I tried to clone my project in a Linux laptop the project for some reason appears Broken. In my projects window in Netbeans it says something like:

NameOfProject (Broken)

I tried to open the files inside the project and it appeared an error that said: "Not all requested modules can be enabled...." (see the image).

This is a screenshot of my laptop with netbeans opened and with the error, you can notice the "broken" thing it says next to the project name:

[image]

Comment: my guess is it is a problem with the netbeans install rather than the project. You are missing most of the modules you would need for java development, did you get the C++ or PHP version of netbeans or find a copy someone else installed? Try downloading and reinstalling.

Comment: I downloaded the full version from the official web site: https://netbeans.org/downloads/. Ok I will try that